# My kitchen faucet is barely running

Tags: plumbing-fixture

my faucet when i woke this morning barely has water running out of it in the kitchen. What would cause this all  of a sudden. It was fine last night

Comment: Does the faucet valve still work, or is this slow drip when the valve is open?

Answer (score 1):

If the faucets throughout the rest of the home are fine, then just unscrew the cap at the end of the faucet. Within it is an aerator - basically a metal and plastic filter that also slows the water down. You've probably gotten a bit of something from within the pipes stuck in it. Typically they just pop open and can be cleaned out with a toothpick or such, but you can also soak it in vinegar for an hour to eat away the junk from within it.

Once it's clean, screw it back in and you should be fine. (If this was the cause)

Comment: Once you have the aerator off turn on the water. It should come out full blast. If cleaning doesn't improve the flow to your satisfaction you can buy a new aerator at the hardware store.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the faucet needs a re-build. It may be just an $8 kit to replace some springs & washers. Or, you may need to replace both cartridges at $8 each or a single cartridge at $40. But, whichever yours needs the faucet will be returned to like new operation with the same longevity. Though it wasn't used, the water's pressure was still working on it throughout the night.